# Is Firebird good embedded DB for ASP.NET? Which else?

Tags: asp.net, sql, database, firebird, embedded-database

Looking for a good embedded db for my asp.net apps while trying to avoid SQLExpress (*I need it to be a downloable file(s) with no need to install at server*), I found Firebird. But:

According to this:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database#Firebird_Embedded

> It has the same features as the classic and superserver version of Firebird, except that *two or more THREADS (not just applications) cannot access the same database* at the same time. So Firebird embedded acts as a local server for a single threaded client accessing its databases (that means it **doesn't work properly for ASP.NET** web applications)

According to this http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/development-net-provider/, however, there *are* some ASP.NET providers released.

> Weekly builds of the ADO.NET Data Provider, the ASP.NET Web Providers and the DDEX provider can be found here.

So the question is: *is it or is it not a good embedded db alternative to use in asp.net?*

If not, what would you recommend instead?

Comment: I have fixed the wikipedia article , firebird 2.5 embedded is fully multithreaded and it is fully supported for asp.net http://blog.cincura.net/231742-firebird-embedded-in-comparison-to-sql-server-compact-edition-4/

Comment: @Mariuz: very well, thank you! You should have posted it as an answer.

Comment: I have posted as answer too,o forgot that you can't vote on comments

Comment: You can also use MS Access as a embedded DB if it suits your requirements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have fixed the wikipedia article , firebird 2.5 embedded is fully multithreaded and it is fully supported for asp.net 
http://blog.cincura.net/231742-firebird-embedded-in-comparison-to-sql-server-compact-edition-4/

Also from what i have read on jiri's blog it is possible to run it on azure
http://blog.cincura.net/232332-using-firebird-inside-azure-without-vm-role/
and on amazon 
http://blog.cincura.net/232333-amazons-ec2-micro-instance-and-firebird/

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is. And I believe it is one of your best options.

Specially because you will be running it in a non MS environment. I know PostgreSQL is a good Open Source DB, but it does not have an embedded version.

Your other option is [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/).

Comment: Firebird embedded works well and you can switch very eaysilly with full version if you need it.

Comment: @Hughes You bet! I only mentioned SQLite because OP needs to know the options.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Is it OK in multithreaded environment like web app though? Because as far as I know SQLite has (or had) issues due to lack of proper locking mechanism (whole DB would be locked on update, making all other clients wait). Is this a problem or not?

Comment: As for SQLite, I wouldn't know. What's stopping you from installing a Firebird server? It's such a straightforward process. Embedded Firebird is for stand alone apps.

Comment: I want to put it at shared hosting server, so I'm not sure if I would be allowed to do that.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that might be worth looking at is [SQL Compact](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/30/new-embedded-database-support-with-asp-net.aspx). The latest version works with ASP.NET and runs in-process. All you need to deploy is a couple of DLLs.

I must confess I don't really know anything about Firebird so can't compare it directly.

Comment: I'm sorry I should have mentioned I'm not interested in any MS solution (need to run on mono).

Comment: In that case SQL Compact is definitely not for you as it's managed code